# Appcelerator Titanium build error about log-server-port masks the real error

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

This is relatively minor, and I wasn't able to find any other record of this issue, but it cost me several stressful hours. I'm considering opening an Appcelerator Jira ticket about this bug, so any feed back is welcome before I do so. Questions: Are there any other workarounds besides what I wrote below? What are some better ways to log the actual error?

**Environment**

Titanium SDK: 7.0.2.GA
Javascript Engine: V8 
Platform & version: iOS 11.2
Device Details: iOS simulator (iPhone 7+)
Host Operating System: OS X 10.13 64 bit
Node Version: 7.10.0
Titanium CLI: 5.0.14
Npm Version: 4.2.0

**Description**

When building an iOS app and there is an issue connecting to the iOS log-server, it always output "Another process is currently bound to port xxxxx" even if there is another server connection issue such as the port not existing.

**Workaround**

Figure out the real issue by logging the actual error within the sdk itself (at ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.0.2.GA/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js in the determineLogServerPort function).

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create a different type of error with the server. For example, my /etc/hosts file did not have an entry for 127.0.0.1 localhost, so the actual node error was 'ENOTFOUND'.
2. Create a new titanium app with `appc ti new`.
3. Build with appc ti build -p ios

**Actual Result**

Build errors out with following text:

```
[ERROR] Another process is currently bound to port 27973
[ERROR] Set a unique <log-server-port> between 1024 and 65535 in the <ios> section of the tiapp.xml
```

**Expected Result**

More detailed error. I.E. Something like:

`Failed to create/connect to log server port with error "[error given by node net package]".`
Followed by suggested solution. For example if the node error was EADDRINUSE, then you could still use the existing error message. But if it's another error, log accordingly so the user has the best information for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the ticket with appcelerator here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25872

They have just marked it as closed so it will hopefully be included in the next sdk version.

Answer (score 2):

Close current emulator running and try again
when emulator was opened by xcode, I got such issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are executing the app with same App name and ID.
If there is a change, please delete the app from device and retake the build.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was what was mentioned as a solution in the JIRA ticket on appcelerator https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25872.

I had recently moved to a new Mac and migrated everything, it created a copy of my host file renaming it but didn't update main one so it had no reference to the localhost in there. Once this was fixed it was building no problem again.

Below is what is in the host file.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Hope that helps someone, didn't see the answer on JIRA at first glance.

Comment: I had recently moved to a new Mac and migrated everything, and now I am getting this issue. Can you explain the steps to fix this? Where is the host file located?

Comment: Nvm thought we were talking about a specific host file for titanium. For everyone else on a Mac, go to /private/etc/hosts